# For the angles a and b it is given that:-

Tags: trigonometry

For the angles $a$ and $b$ it is given that:

$\sin a = 0.6$, $\sin b = 0.8$, $\cos a = 0.8$ and $\cos b = 0.6$

Find the value of $\sin( a + b)$

with out calculator :-

thanks all - happy mother day ♥ ♥ ♥

Comment: my answer :- sin(a+b) = sina + sinB = 0.6 + 0.8 = 1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angle sum identity says $\sin(a+b)=\sin a \cos b + \sin b \cos a$.  Plug in the values you are given.  The single digit numbers make a calculator optional.

Comment: sin a = cos b and sin b = cos a

Comment: @MomenOsama:  that is true, so for your specific problem you can say $\sin (a+b)=\sin^2a+ \cos^2a$.  The calculation is the same.  The identity is true whatever the $a,b$

Comment: so :- sin a cos b + sin b + cos b = 0.6 *0.6 +0.8 *0.8 = 0.36 + 0.64 = 1

Comment: @MomenOsama:  that is correct.

Comment: thanks all   Ross Millikan -  Inceptio - and happy mother day ♥ ♥ ♥

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks and wish you the same .:)

Use $\sin(a+b)= \sin a \cos b+\cos a\sin b$.

Comment: the two answers is very good thanks Inceptio and Ross Millikan ♥ ♥ ♥